# Microsoft Reporting DLLs in medium trust environment

Tags: .net, dll, rackspace, mosso

My host Rackspace Cloud Sites have a modified Medium Trust environment. One of our legacy applications which we are moving onto the server uses the following DLLs:

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll

My understanding is that these DLLs work in a medium trust environment if deployed to the GAC. Sadly Rackspace will not do this for me. What options do I have apart from moving to a different plan? Deploying the DLLs to the bin does not work as the permissions are incorrect.

Could I decompile the DLLs and make them work in a medium trust environment?

**UPDATE**
I think the only way I can go is to use a Windows Cloud Server